# How do you validate a checkbox in Angular on submit with a show/hide?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have Angular setup to disable a submit button until a checkbox is checked. What I want though, is that when you click submit a validation message appears saying you have to check "agree" first. I don't think the button being disabled is doing me any favors, but I'm not sure what to try next. Here's my code:

```
<div ng-app class="test">
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree_checkbox" ng-model="checked">
    <label for="agree_checkbox">I agree.</label>

    <div class="validation">You have to agree first.</div>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!checked">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to do this? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapunahele/5y9tqo67/32/)

Thanks,
K-

Comment: You could `ng-show` the div when `ng-click` event is done on button && the checkbox `!checked`

Comment: Thank you, @tektiv. I have to admit that I'm unsure how to time the events. I edited my fiddle, but it's not right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5y9tqo67/34/)

```
<div ng-app class="test" ng-init="valid=true">
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree_checkbox" ng-model="checked" >
    <label for="agree_checkbox">I agree.</label>

    <div class="validation" ng-if="!valid">You have to agree first.</div>

    <button type="submit" ng-click="valid=checked">Submit</button>
</div>
```

And don't forget to remove:

```
display: none;
color: #fff;
```

from your validation css.

**EDIT:**

And if you want to prevent form from being submitted:

```
 $scope.submit = function() {
      if($scope.valid) {
          console.log('submit form')
      }          
  }
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/5y9tqo67/39/)

Comment: Thank you very much, @SaidKholov. This is exactly what I was looking for. As you can see, i'm still inside the Angular learning curve. This is perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this demo I prepared: http://codepen.io/Samuelson/pen/QbKXer
It checks the checkbox state with javascript.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppController', function($scope){
  $scope.alert = function(index, event){
        if(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
        return;
    } else {
      alert("Hey! " + index);
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the codepen, @Samuelson. I'll definitely keep this one in my pocket.